# Let $F=\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$ and $f=x^2+[2]$. For the field $F$, poly. $f$, let $I=fF[x]$. Let $X=x+I$. Write $X^3\in F[x]/I$ as $uX+v$ for $u,v\in F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $F=\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ and $f=x^2+[2]$. For the field $F$ and the polynomial $f$ consider the ideal $I=fF[x]$. Let $X=x+I\in F[x]/I$. Express the element $X^3\in F[x]/I$ as $uX+v$ where $u,v\in F$

My solution: $X^2+[2]=[0]$ and so $X^2=[-2]=[5]$. Therefore $X^3=XX^2=X([5])=[5]X$. This gives $X^3=[5]X$, i.e. $u=5,v=0$. Is this correct? If so, have I made a mistake by putting the square brackets around $5$?

Comment: I think because $X$ and $X^3$ are both in $F[x]/I$, $u$ and $v$ should be in $F[x]$. May I know the source of this question?

Comment: @AlanWang in any case was my solution correct? It was an assignment question

Comment: This seems correct, although if you are using the square-bracket notation then $u=[5]$ and $v=[0]$ are elements of $F$ (as opposed to $u=5$ and $v=0$ which are not). For that matter, $u=[-2]$ and $u=[-9]$ and $u=[7000005]$ are also equally correct.